# How to use the result of one .agg as a parameter in another?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to aggregate some data in a pandas dataframe, with a few basic summary functions, but then I need some that are functions of some of these summary functions.

What I am currently doing is:

```
df_summary = df.groupby(['list', 'of', 'column', 'names'])['column to summarize'].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'some other functions'])
df_summary["other_summary1"] = df_summary["mean"] * constant1 + constant2
df_summary["other_summary2"] = math.log(df_summary["other_summary1"])
```

My instincts tell me this is not the idiomatic way to do this, and that surely there is a way to do a transformation of a function within the `.agg()`. Is there?